# Retrieve Oauth2 Authorization code and Access token through API 2022 Implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-data-jpa

[image]

Based on the diagram you can see above (Oauth authrization flow). Reference https://youtu.be/oKzeHshquCs?t=1949

1. Using user credentials (username, password), we are attempting to
   get an authorization code (login).
2. Authorization code received.
3. Using the received authorization code we are now requesting an
   access token.
4. When access token is given. This access token will be
   now used to access the resource server (as Bearer Token).

I would like to ask how to implement this using API, using the latest implementation of OAuth2. Using custom REST API's on the Authorization Server.

Scenario: using two api's ('/auth/code' then ''auth/token'')

1. Using user credentials (username, password) the user will request on
   api '/auth/code', where authorization_code as the response.
2. Using the recieved authorization code (from #1), we will request an access
   token on '/auth/token'. Access token will be used as bearer token on
   the authorization server.
3. Or if we can do this two step (#1 and #2 above) on one API process (auth/token) would also be great.

Do you have any working project in regards with this?

I have explored the code of [Baeldung](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-authorization-server), but based on this implementation, it is still using the default implementation of spring security. It would be my great pleasure if there are Senpai's out there can help me with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such API to get an authorization code directly passing the user credentials. Usually, there would be an API (/as/authorization), which redirects the user to the login page. Once the user enters his credentials, he will be redirected to the target application with the authorization code in `code` as the query parameter of the URL. (You need to configure your app's URL as a redirect URL or callback URL in the Identity provider)

This code is usually short-lived and can't be used more than a time. (i.e) You can use this code only once to get an access token. When you exchange the code with an access token, you should be seeing refresh_token (if you granted access to refresh_token grant_type in the IdP) as well with which you can request tokens in the future.

You need to configure all these things in an Identity Provider. This could be PingIdentity, Auth0, etc.

1. Make a call to /as/authorization API
2. Once user enters his credentials and redirected to the target application, extract the code from the query parameter and make a call to token API (oauth/token) to get access_token and refresh_token
3. Once the access_token is expired, use the refresh_token to get a new access_token (grant_type should be refresh_token).
4. Once the refresh_token is expired, you need to again get the authorization_code again with the /as/authorization API.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Based on what you said "There's no such API to get an authorization code directly passing the user credentials" - so there no possible way we can get an auth_code in a custom way? In cases where you have multiple application/systems and only using one authorization server, so it means we can only redirect them to one specific login link "he will be redirected to the target application", what if we have multiple logins with different applications? Is it not feasible?

Comment: You can configure multiple systems/applications in one authorization server as OAuth Clients. For each OAuth client, you can configure the link to your login page and the redirect/callback URL which points to the target application you're trying to log in to where you would get the authorization_code.